# Is it good Idea to have Angle & Distance struct or class

Tags: java, c#, class, struct

Is it good idea to have `Angle` & `Distance` `struct`, instead of just passing `float` or `double` around?

For example in C#, I can make a `Angle` struct, it would have methods such as:

```
angle.Sin();
angle.Cos();
```

That way I don't have to think if I'm using Radians or 360 Deg.

And for `Distance`, `Speed`, ... etc. I can do the same

Is it good design to build such class and structs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some advantages of setting up classes/structs:

1. You can deal with different units.  You already mentioned not having to worry about radians/degrees, but that also applies to distance (you could set up a distance in `km`, `cm`, `miles`, `furlongs`, whatever) and other measurements.
2. Doing this prevents accidentally mixing up incommensurate values.  If you use `double` for everything, you could accidentally say `x = y;` where `x` is a measurement of distance and `y` is a measurement of mass, for example.  Defining your own classes to represent measurements prevents this, if you do it right.  You can also prevent adding and subtracting unlike measurements.  (Handling multiplication and division is interesting, though...)
3. In the case of angles, you can do things like treating 90° the same as 450° or -270° (i.e. write an `equals()` function that treats them as equal).

Answer (score 2):

The downside of the *domain* classes is arithmetics. Imagine, that you want to compute the arc length. In case of `double` it's quite simple:

```
 double radius = 12.345;
 double angle = Math.PI / 6.0;

 double arcLength = radius * angle;
```

In case of *Java* this simple solution turns into something combersome

```
 Distance radius = new Distance(12.345); 
 Angle angle = new Angle(Math.PI / 6.0);

 // please, notice that we lose safety with getValue(), but "gain" wordiness
 Distance arcLength = new Distance(radius.getValue() * angle.getValue());

 // An alternative version can be even worse:
 // Distance arcLength = radius.multiply(angle);
```

In *C#* you can alleviate this wordiness by using *operators*:

```
 Distance radius = 12.345; // implicit operator at work 
 Angle angle = Math.PI / 6.0; // implicit operator at work 

 Distance arcLength = radius * angle; // * operator
```

However, even in case of C# you may found that you have to *constantly updating* the exitsing domains: imagine that you want to introduce `Speed` class. You have to think over if, say, `Speed * Angle`, `Speed / Distance` are allowed and in case they are what are the resultss types (e.g. does `Speed / Distance == Frequency`?)

Comment: Having a generalized measurement class where you could specify the degrees of different types of measurements might be useful (e.g. Speed would be distance=1, time=-1, mass=0; Acceleration would be distance=1, time=-2, mass=0, since it's measured in something like m/(sec^2).  Is there a library like that?

Comment: @ajb: it's an improvement; however, the problem doesn't disappear: `Angle` is a special case, 
since you can, say get `Sin(Angle)`, but can't `Sin(Mass)`. In 3d space there's a problem with `Angle` addition (or multiplication as groups theory puts it): `A + B != B + A` etc. In business routines we have troubles with `Currency` arithmetics: you can add up, say, *dollars*, but can't sum *dollars* and *euros*.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your ultimate purpose, I would suggest you consider using the .NET "Complex" structure in System.Numerics. In that way the Angle & Distance would be vectors, and you can operate on those directly using any of the many included math functions. You mentioned having an `angle.sin()` and `angle.cos()` method. You wouldn't need those, since the Complex structure includes a `FromPolarCoordinates(Double, Double)`method to convert your angle & distance to X & Y coordinates. You can also perform matrix calculations on Complex numbers, and make your code generic & re-usable for many other types of applications.